# SSH Not Found On Cmd Session Started From C# Program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssh, cmd

When I launch cmd.exe from a C# Program in Visual Studio, I get an error saying 'ssh is not an internal or external program' but when I launch cmd via Win + R -> cmd.exe, there is no problem. I checked the PATH variable and its identical in both. What could cause this weird behaviour?

Code:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C ssh user@123.456.789.0";
process.Start();
```

Comment: Is ssh on a windows drive or on a linux partition?  You need the full path for both ssh and cmd.exe.

Comment: @jdweng I have supplied it with both full path of ssh: "C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" and full path of cmd "C:\Windows\system32cmd.exe"  still nothing.

Comment: Try setting project properties to x86.

Comment: @jdweng It's configured as "Any CPU" (It's a C# Forms app) and that is the only option.

Comment: You have to add a new configuration for x86.  It is in the dropdown where Any CPU is located.

Comment: @jdweng Setting it to x64 solved it Thanks!

Comment: Any CPU defaults to 32 bit mode.

Comment: There is no need to run `cmd.exe` to run `ssh.exe`. The [process class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process) can be used to run any executable without usage of `cmd.exe`. I recommend to read the Microsoft documentation about [File System Redirector](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector). Then you should have the knowledge why the execution of 64-bit `ssh.exe` in `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH` failed from within a 32-bit EXE running in 32-bit execution environment and starting 32-bit `cmd.exe` in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

Comment: The usage of `C:\Windows\Sysnative\OpenSSH\ssh.exe` would have helped for your 32-bit executable running on 64-bit Windows. You hopefully know that OpenSSH is installed only on the newest Windows 10 versions. So your application will not work on older versions of Windows 10 or Windows 7/8/8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the build configuration, making it x64 instead of "Any CPU" solved the problem. See comments for more detail.